# pubnub and head.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe, head.js, pubnub

Has anyone managed to integrate [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) and head.js properly?

[Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) expect me to put their script at the bottom of the page with a `<div>` tag just before it. This ensures that the ` tag is completely loaded by the time the javascript is called last.

The thing is, the rest of my application and pubnub are loaded through head.js so it keeps happening that the JS files are loaded before the pubnub subscribe/publish key and its subscribing/publishing to 'demo' rather than my own area of pubnub...

Is there any example anywhere or way for me to just screw off this `<div>` element and pass in the credentials directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for asking about PubNub with [Head.JS](http://headjs.com/) usage.  I will help you get started quickly.  The following is an example of how to us PubNub with [Head.JS](http://headjs.com/).  First call the head.js() function as you normally would including the PubNub JS Lib.  Then call PUBNUB.init({}) function inside the head.js callback:

```
head.js("/jquery.js", "http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.3.1.min.js", function() {
    // CREATE A PUBNUB  OBJECT
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        'publish_key'   : 'pub-key',
        'subscribe_key' : 'sub-key',
        'ssl'           : false
    });
    pubnub.ready();
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel : 'abc',
        callback : function(message) { alert(message) }
    });
});
```

That's it!  Pretty simple right?  With this code you will be able to use the PubNub Script with [Head.JS](http://headjs.com/) easily.  If there is anything that may be missing from this, please let me know and I will update the code and description.

Comment: thanks that's perfect :) I didn't see much about head JS usage and I hope this helps someone else :) Would be cool to see it in the documentation as well. Thanks for the speedy response via twitter/email and here