# Initializing PubNub without DOM keys

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I could use some help initializing the javascript PubNub interface without having to append divs to the DOM before loading the .js library as recommended by https://pubnub-prod.appspot.com/account-javascript-api-include

I'd like to be able to init PubNub via a function. I tried modifying the solution suggested by this SO question without success: [pubnub and head.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275317/pubnub-and-head-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil from PubNub here.  We've got you covered.  All you have to do is use the following code:

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key   : my_publish_key,
    subscribe_key : my_subscribe_key,
    ssl           : false,
    origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com'
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.